# multiple returns in a react function component isn't working

Tags: reactjs, return, components

While working on my react project I have used the command `<Redirect />`, until yesterday everything was great but right now I have noticed that the returns which are not the main return, the returns inside lambda functions aren't working and aren't changing the URL.

example code:

```
const Register = () => {
   const [errorMessage, setError] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [full_name, setFullname] = useState('');

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userDetails = {email, full_name, password};
        try{
            await axios.post('register', userDetails);
            return <Redirect to={''} />; // isn't working.
        }catch (error){
            setError(error.response.data.error);
        }
    }
    
    return(
```

it means only the last return in the last row i have copied is working and the one
after the post request isn't.
Even if i tried writing stuff like `return (<div></div>);` it isn't working.
I will be glad if someone can help and apologies in advance if it aint clear explanation, it's my first time asking for help here.

Comment: the one after the post isn't working because it is returning for the function, which means it will return <Redirect to={''}/> , You can't return a component for the DOM inside a function, I will recommend you to use useState and then conditionally render the Redirect Component and the last return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use return while using a redirect. You are doing it wrong. While redirecting it would redirect to the specified URL. I see you haven't even added a route to redirect to. If it's just an empty string it wouldn't do anything except maybe re-render the page and also you are putting in the route wrongly. For e.g; if you would like to redirect to the dashboard/homepage on successful registration use it like -

```
const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userDetails = {email, full_name, password};
    try{
        await axios.post('register', userDetails);
       <Redirect to='/' />;
    }catch (error){
       setError(error.response.data.error);
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I think what you can do is use `useNavigate` which was introduced in `react-router-dom v6` for redirection. You can use it like -

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const navigate = useNavigate()

const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userDetails = {email, full_name, password};
        try{
            await axios.post('register', userDetails);
            navigate('/')
        }catch (error){
           setError(error.response.data.error);
        }
    }
```